# Why does ADDRESS function return an error across different worksheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

When I try to count cells that match my criteria using the address function, I get mixed results depending on which sheet the formula is nested.

For example, if I use the following to count the cells equal to 2 on the same sheet, I get the correct answer.

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(4,2,1,TRUE,)&":"&ADDRESS(20,2,1,TRUE,)),2)
```

However, if I move the function to another sheet and modify it to read the following, the `COUNTIF` function returns `#REF!`.

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(4,2,1,TRUE,"Other Sheet")&":"&ADDRESS(20,2,1,TRUE,"Other Sheet")),2)
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it’s really rather simple. `'Other Sheet'!$B$4:'Other Sheet'!$B$20` is not a valid reference.

So, instead, something like this might work:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(4,2,1,TRUE,"Other Sheet")&":"&ADDRESS(20,2,1,TRUE)),2)
```

It produces `'Other Sheet'!$B$4:$B$20`.